# Create multiple field form and email response on backend from within app

Tags: iphone, xcode, forms, ios4, textinput

I am trying to figure out and get some info  on how to collect all info inputed on a specific view on separate text fields from within the app, then collect all these into one string and have this data emailed to a specific email after user hits send button. Im basically trying to create a form that the user will fill and then submit, surprisingly I can not find any useful data or examples pertaining to this here or online. Any useful input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hii,

you can create your own data entry form with UItableviewController -Adding Form Elements in Cell.content Views but if your new then go for this Library to generate Data Entry Forms -

https://github.com/ittybittydude/IBAForms

Hope this helps,